# How to pop up "Console Windows Properties" WITHOUT "Right-clicking the title bar"?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line

I want to pop up the "Console Windows Properties" without right-clicking the title bar → Defaults (**not** Properties)

[image]

My customer"s"  just keep complaining to me about how to change the "Console Font-size".

His/Her (my customers') OS is Windows XP, and mine is Windows 7.

I think modifying the registry key is probably a feasible way, but I want to pop up this window:

[image]

Instead of modifying the registry table lest his/her registry be broken.

Does any wizard have an idea? Using APIs? (Internal/external) commands (preferred)?

Appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a shortcut that is configured to the right settings.

For any console window you could either left click the icon on the upper left corner of the console window. Or press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>. Sending the right keys can also be done from a console program using [.NET SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) or [WinSDK SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: THX, but what I want to do is to pop up this window automatically.

Comment: Automatically? When and how? What is the Trigger/Event to open the popup?

Comment: I am also a programmer :). `system()` or some APIs can be used to trigger this popup I think.

Comment: For example (in C/C++): `system("RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll");` can pop up the "Remove Hardware" window.

Comment: @KVD: I updated my answer.

Comment: Appreciate your help. :-)